# Extra lines when handling multiple xml files with xslt

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml files :

File01:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FirstTag>
    <SecondTag>
        <Name>MyName</Name>
        <Age>Age</Age>
    </SecondTag>
</FirstTag>
```

File02:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Export>
    <Module>
        <Object>
            <CreatedBy>FullName</CreatedBy>
            <CreatedOn>2009-07-07</CreatedOn>
            <Description>SomeDescription</Description>
        </Object>
    </Module>
</Export>
```

Main file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<index>
    <entry>file01</entry>
    <entry>file02</entry>
</index>
```

I want to combine them using the following xsl :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="index">
    <NEW-XML>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="entry"/>
    </NEW-XML>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document(concat(.,'.xml'))"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FirstTag/SecondTag">
    <FIRST-FILE>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </FIRST-FILE>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Export/Module/Object">
    <SECOND-FILE>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </SECOND-FILE>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After i make the conversion i get empty lines . Can someone help me please ? 
This is the resulting file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NEW-XML>
    <FIRST-FILE>
        MyName
        Age
    </FIRST-FILE>


        <SECOND-FILE>
            FullName
            2009-07-07
            SomeDescription
        </SECOND-FILE>

</NEW-XML>
```

Comment: Did you find out that the empty lines cause a technical problem or are we just talking about the beauty of the XML file? If the latter is the case I would not spend any effort on removing them. What looks a little bit more disturbing to me is the fact that you convert from a well structured XML format to a loosely formatted plain text format within your files. Or, are you rather concerned about the lacking tags and not the extra newlines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty lines can be (probably*) removed by including

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="FirstTag Export Module"/>
```

at the top level of your stylesheet.

Alternatively, add the following template:

```
 <xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())]"/>
```

I share the concern expressed by Marcus Rickert over your output format.

--
(*) depending on your specific processor

Comment: The content inside FIRST-FILE and SECOND-FILE is of no interest for me . I don't understand why i shold use additional commands to remove empty lines that don't exist either in my input files or in my schema.

Comment: @LucianFlorea I am afraid it would take too long to explain, but the empty lines do come from your input. Anyway, I have added another option to my answer.

Comment: If they come from my input it is ok . I was thinking it was a problem in my XSL. Thank you for your answer.